# For every integer $a$, if $32 \nmid ((a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))$ then $a$ is even

Tags: linear-algebra

Statement 1: for every integer $a$, if $32 \nmid  ((a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))$ then $a$ is even

I just want to double check my work because I'm not sure of my answers but the question asks,

a) Rewrite the given statement in symbolic form.

$\forall a \in \Bbb Z , 32  \nmid  ((a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7)) \implies |a|$

b) State hypothesis of Statement 1.

$\forall a\in\mathbb{Z} , 32  \nmid  ((a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))$

c) State conclusion of Statement 1.

$|a|$

d) State the converse of Statement 1.

$|a| \implies \forall a\in\mathbb Z , 32  \nmid  ((a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))$

e) State the negation of Statement 1.

$\exists a \in \mathbb Z , 32  \nmid  ((a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7)) \implies -|a|$

f) State the contrapositive of Statement 1.

$-|a| \implies \exists a\in \mathbb Z , 32  \nmid  ((a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))$

g) Prove or disprove Statement 1.

I'm a bit stuck on this question.

Can someone verify my answers? I'm not too sure of it…. If I got something wrong can you explain what I did wrong?

Comment: `\!\,` doesn't make any sense. That's a backspace followed by a space....

Comment: What do you mean by $|a|$ and $-|a|$?

Comment: Absolute value a and - the absolute value of a

Comment: Then I clearly am misinterpreting something. What did you mean by $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: I mean 'then' a is even.

Comment: Did I use that symbol in the wrong context?

Comment: "Then $a$ is even" would be $\implies 2\mid a$ or similar.

Comment: So were my absolute values all incorrect...?

Comment: how would I write the negation of that? Sorry, I've been up late at night. I just realized my mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are denoting the statement "$a$ is even" by $|a|$. (Also: As a commenter mentioned, a more appropriate notation would be $(2 \mid a)$.)

(a) Use parentheses for more clarity:

$$ \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}\ (32 \nmid (a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7) \Rightarrow |a| ) $$

This is to signify that the quantifier $\forall a$ applies to the entire implication.

(b) Now, this is tricky. "$\forall a$" is actually a quantifier. You can say that if it is understood that we are only working with integers, the hypothesis is $32 \nmid (a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7)$. If not, the hypothesis should be $(a \in \mathbb{Z}) \wedge (32 \nmid (a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))$.

(c) Ok.

(d) Again, two versions here. If $a$ is understood to be an integer, the converse is

$$|a| \Rightarrow (32 \nmid (a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7)  ).$$

The full converse is

$$|a| \Rightarrow ((a \in \mathbb{Z}) \wedge (32 \nmid (a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))  ).$$

(e) The negation of an implication $p \to q$ is $p \wedge \neg q$. The full negation is

$$((a \in \mathbb{Z}) \wedge (32 \nmid (a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))  ) \wedge -|a|.$$

You can remove $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ if it is understood.

(f) This should be

$$ -|a| \Rightarrow ((a \notin \mathbb{Z}) \vee (32 \mid (a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7))  ).$$

Again, you can remove $a \notin \mathbb{Z}$ if $a$ is understood to be an integer.

(g) The statement is true. Prove it using the contrapositive in (f). If $a$ is odd, write it as $2k + 1$ and expand $(a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7)$. It should be clear that this is divisible by 32.

Comment: What do you mean by if a is understood to be an integer?

Comment: When working with logic statements, it is usual that the "universe of discourse" is clear - this means that when a variable like $a$ appears, we understand automatically what values $a$ is allowed to take. In your question, for example, we can say that it is clear to all of us that $a$ is a real number. If that's all we can assume, we have to include $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ in the hypothesis. BUT: if we agree that we all understand $a$ is an integer (by virtue of "for any integer $a$"), then you get a simpler statement.

Comment: I see, so in my case I wouldn't put a∈ℤ in the hypothesis. Also, where did you get 2k + 1?

Comment: An integer $a$ is odd if it can be expressed as $a = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: oh okay I see now. I realized that my |a| is the symbol for a is even was totally off and that it's a|2. How would I write the negation of that?

Comment: If $a$ is an integer, $2 \nmid a$ means that $a$ is odd.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks. I'm new to all of this. I understand the solution now though.